# ajax call to web method does not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

i have this ajax call

```
   function findPICKey() {
        filter = document.getElementById('MainCT_dtvJobVac_PIC').value;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json;',
            data: "{listuser:" + JSON.stringify(resultarr) + ", keyword:'" + JSON.strigify(filter)+ "'}",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'SvcAutoComplete.asmx/GetPICKey',
            success: function (result) {
                result = JSON.parse(result.d);
                document.getElementById('<%= dtvJobVac.FindControl("PICKey").ClientID %>').value = result;

           },
               error: function (result) {
                   alert("error getting pic key");
               }
           })
    }
```

web method

```
   [WebMethod]
        public string GetPICKey(List<BO> listuser, string keyword)
        {
            //List<BO> ListObj = new List<BO>();
            //ListObj = (List<BO>)Session["ListPIC"];
            //ListObj = listuser;
            //string key = string.Empty;

            //for (int i = 0; i < ListObj.Count; i++)
            //{
            //    if(ListObj[i].label == keyword)
            //    {
            //        key = ListObj[i].value;
            //        break;
            //    }
            //}

            //return key;
            return "";
        }
```

for some reason my web method not called, i put a break point, but it does not triggered, what i do wrong here? btw resultarr is an object.

Comment: it is working now, but the problem now is i have 2 action in my button "       <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btSubmitPIC" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="findPICKey()" OnClick="btSubmitPIC_Click"/>" my web method actually trigerred, but it finish after onclick even called, this cause i dont't get key value which i need to store to database, how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Just checking, but you know your second stringify is spelt wrong?
"JSON.strigify" :)

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is in

```
 data: "{listuser:" + JSON.stringify(resultarr) + ", keyword:'" + JSON.strigify(filter)+ "'}",
it should be 

 data: {listuser:"+ JSON.stringify(resultarr) +" , keyword:" + JSON.strigify(filter)+ "},

or
data: {listuser:JSON.stringify(resultarr) , keyword:JSON.strigify(filter)},
```

Answer (score 0):

if you call webservice from localhost, you should check url

eq:

```
http://localhost/HenryChunag/SvcAutoComplete.asmx
```

url should be :

```
url: '/HenryChunag/SvcAutoComplete.asmx/GetPICKey'
```